# How to change ckeditor icons color

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Very simple, I want to change the icons used in ckeditor from black to white as the menu will be on a dark background ...
I have already spent some-time trying to alter the CCS but no joy, I'm fairly certain I need to change the icon properties but the last time I tired the box containing the image went black and I could n't make out the symbols/icons.

I'd appreciate some clear advice before attempting again... cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a quick reversal of the icons using a gradient map adjustment layer in Photoshop.

See how this looks for you:

- http://postimg.org/image/4by2k00yv/ (icons.png)
- http://postimg.org/image/gf3e7kc13/ (icons-hidpi.png)