# How to change ckeditor toolbar background color (to black) and button/icon foreground color (to white)?

Tags: ckeditor

How can the background of CKEditor be changed to black, and the icons be changed to white -- for a dark website?

Using CKEditor 4 (4.11.4, source code version).

The background of the editor can be changed to black, but the buttons/icons become very dim and barely visible.

In [ckeditor_directory_path]/skins/moono-lisa/skin.js:
`baseColor = colorBrightness( uiColor, -1 ),`

In [ckeditor_directory_path]/skins/moono-lisa/config.js:
`config.uiColor = '#000000';`

This changes the editor background to black, but also results in dim buttons/icons. The icons need to be a brighter colour in order to be visible.

How can the icons be made white (`#FFFFFF`)?

---

There is a similar question, but the answer was not helpful. [How to change ckeditor icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945781/how-to-change-ckeditor-icons-color)

Hopefully in this case (using the "moono-lisa" skin), it is possible to change the background and button/icon colours using only CSS/Javascript/etc. and not create an entire set of graphical icons. The moono-lisa skin does not have an 'icons' directory (as other instructions regarding CKEditor version 3 have suggested): https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/How-change-toolbar-icon

So I don't know what the next step should be. Thanks in advance for your help.

(Update: edited to remove "tinyMCE" tags. I was going to warn other users not to use tinyMCE -- its "multiple editors per page" functionality is a nightmare to set up and the official documentation for tinyMCE 4 is cheerfully wrong. Numerous Stack Overflow topics only add to the confusion with no apparent correct answer. After days of wasted effort to work around several other tinyMCE issues, there seems to be no solution, hence I finally switched to CKEditor. But the deficiencies of tinyMCE are a separate issue. Hopefully CKEditor is a better option, although the documentation for basic features like background/icon colors, etc., aren't much of an improvement over tinyMCE -- which leads me here to ask this question...)

Answer (score 1):

I've found two answers:

[Moono Dark](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/moono-dark)

[Moono Dark Biskrem](https://github.com/BiskremMuhammad/ckeditor-basic-moono-dark-biskrem)

Hope this helps someone looking for alternatives. If you have further thoughts about the question itself, that's also great, too; please add a comment. :)

---

Comment: one way of setting up the color is using `config.uiColor` property https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-uiColor. You can find example for its usage here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/uicolor.html. If however you wanted to change background color as well as icons then you need to change the editor skin (AS YOU DID). Skins can be found in editor add-ons repo - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/skins/all.